# Text and button are displacing when changing size of the screen

Tags: html, css, material-design, angular2-material

when I'm changing browser window size the text that was centred in the progress circle displaced away from its real position and button also changes its normal position(which was in the centre in the main container) like this:

[image]

the text 60 displaced from center of circle also button pushed to the left side that was originally in the center, how can I retain them into original position even if I change browser window size, here is `css` I applied

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.button1 {
float: right;
background-color: red;
width: 50%;
margin-right: 188px !important;
}
.main_container{
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 94%;
}

.card_styling{
background-color: lightgrey;
margin-top: 36px;
padding-top: 119px;
min-height: 63%;
}
.circle{
height: 16%;
float: right;
margin-top: -13%;
}
#time{
float: right;
margin-top: -10%;
margin-right: 5%;
font-weight: bold;
}
.title_styling{
margin-top: -87px;
margin-bottom: 97px; 
}
.content_style{
margin-bottom: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container" class="main_container">

<md-card class="card_styling">
<md-progress-circle class="circle" mode="determinate" 
[value]="rangeObs |   async ">   
</md-progress-circle>
<p id="time">{{percentage}}</p>

<md-card-title class="title_styling">Introduction to computer
</md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
    <p class="content_style">some text</p>
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
       <md-radio-button>
           {{d.label}}
       </md-radio-button>
</div>

<md-card-actions>
    <button md-button class="button1">Submit</button>
</md-card-actions>

</md-card-content>
</md-card>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

1.)Div the circle and the number 60 together in one group

2.) Put the submit button inside the greybox div

In order for them to stay static you have to group them together